# Cannot implement byline into posts container in single.php

Tags: posts, loop

I tried inputting PHP byline code in `page.php`, `single.php` and `page-sidebar.php` inside of the loop, under the title. As I thought, the byline appears on pages but not on posts. Also, I noticed my single post pages do not contain a loop like most other themes.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<p><?php echo "By ";?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
```

Right now, the best I can do is get the byline to show outside of the content box on posts: [example](http://cultmontreal.com/2015/10/ville-marie-film-review/)

On `single.php`, as I mentioned earlier, there is no loop to put the PHP code into. The following is the code I see on `single.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<p><?php echo "By ";?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>

<?php
// GET CMB DATA 
$cmb_single_style = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cmb_single_style', true ); 
if ( $cmb_single_style == "multi" || $cmb_single_style == "multi_sidebar" ) { 
    get_template_part( 'inc/templates/template_single_multi' ); 
} else {
    get_template_part('inc/templates/template_single');     
}    
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Here is my code: <p>By <?php the_author_post_link();?></p>

Comment: That code looks somewhat incomplete without `if` part to that `else`. Had you tried with template part mentioned in it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. When I copy/pasted the code, it got commented out. Here is the full code:          <?php get_header(); ?>


<p><?php echo "By ";?>  <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>

 <?php 




    // GET CMB DATA
    $cmb_single_style = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cmb_single_style', true);




    if ($cmb_single_style == "multi" || $cmb_single_style == "multi_sidebar") {
       
        get_template_part('inc/templates/template_single_multi');   

    } else {

        get_template_part('inc/templates/template_single');     




    }


?>


  
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: your post's content is being rendered inside `template_single_multi.php` and `template_single.php`. those are the files you need to edit (or duplicate in a child theme).

Answer (score 1):

> On single.php, as I mentioned earlier, there is no loop to put the PHP code into.

If your theme follows WordPress standards, there **will** be a loop. You'll likely find it in the Template Part files that are being called in your If/Then statement.

Look for the following files under `[theme folder]\templates\`:

- template_single_multi.php
- template_single.php

> Right now, the best I can do is get the byline to show outside of the content box on posts

Depending on how your theme is built, there are a couple ways to accomplish this. I would start by searching your theme for calls to `the_title` or `get_the_post_title`. This should give you a list of places where the title is echoed to the screen. Most likely, you'll find it in the Template Parts described above, or in functions.php

If the individual Template Parts call something like `<?php the_title() ?>`, then you can add your code right below that.

If the Title is being called inside a function or hook, this gives you greater flexibility. You can add your code to it, like above. Or, with some advanced WordPress knowledge, you could write your own hook or filter to modify the original function. Keeping your code cleaner.